# Using mongodb for storing almost all website text

Tags: mongodb

Like most web developers, I used to use mysql for most of my db needs. But now I'm interested in mongodb, and trying to integrate it into a project I'm building. Problem is, because I don't have much experience with mongodb, I'm having a little difficulty deciding on a feature. I never had a live website using mongodb, so I'm not really sure if it's good for this.

This site will be available in several languages. So I decided to store all text in some place, where I will be able to programatically fetch needed ones in correct language. If I was using mysql, I would definitely NOT use it for this purpose. But I'm using mongodb, and it seems logical to use it for storing a lot of text and later fetching.

Do you think it's a good idea? It's a document store, so it should be ideal for this, but I'm also imagining having lots of queries fetching data from db, and it doesn't seem so good...

Also, do you think mongodb being local or remote should make a difference on decision?

Answer (score 0):

And the exact problem is?

I assume you have something like that in MySQL

| key | language | text |

It's trivial to translate that into a MongoDB like

{
  key: ....,
  translations :
{ 'de' : ,
  'en' : ,
}

Answer (score 0):

> Also, do you think mongodb being local or remote should make a difference on decision?

I'll start here. It's almost never good practice to host the database and the web-server on the same box, especially in the age of "cloud computing" where you can buy two small boxes for the price of one large box :)

In some cases it makes sense to keep a small "local copy". But this depends on the hardware you have available.

> Do you think it's a good idea?

As **@Andreas** points out, it's pretty trivial to build a "dictionary" for the various translations:

```
{ key: ...., translations : { 'de' : , 'en' : , }
```

> but I'm also imagining having lots of queries fetching data from db

If you're going to store translations in a DB, they'll have to be queried in some way. Either you have to put it in a cache (APC, Memcache) or local server variables (PHP config files) or a real Database (MongoDB, MySQL).

No matter when you put the data, you're going to have to run multiple queries. MongoDB queries tend to be very fast, especially if the data is regularly accessed and stays in memory.

But don't take my word for it, feel free to test it out.